# SMB access issues Server 2016 from Mac-Catalina

Tags: smb, windows-server-2016, macos-mojave, adobe-illustrator, macos-catalina

I have 2 Macs accessing SMB shares of a Server 2016 and problems occur, constant server connection. Both Macs are in the graphics department.

Currently the problem is for Excel, Adobe Illustrator etc. If they want to overwrite an existing table on an SMB share, Excel hangs up for a moment and the saving process fails. Only a temporary file is created and the table is not overwritten. I have experienced similar problems with Adobe software.

Sometimes at the same time point:15:20h, 17:00h etc. they are thrown out of the structure.

There is an "almost full access" to the drive or share. This means that you have all rights except for changing the permissions.

I have already dealt with this problem in some detail and the core problem here is Apple's support for Windows SMB releases.

The problem affects not only MS Mac Office but also various other software vendors.

The Macs are running Mac OS Version Catalina.

Comment: Make sure the file is not opened by someone else on a different computer. In such a case the file is usually locked and can't be overwritten or deleted no matter what permissions someone has one the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for months with several macs on our network connecting to our Windows Server 2016 SMB shares, after much trial and error the following resolved our issues.

Coincidentally also our design team using adobe suite was the most problematic.

Create the following file:

```
/etc/nsmb.conf
```

With the following contents:

```
[default]
signing_required=no
streams=yes
file_ids_off=yes
protocol_vers_map=2
```

This can be done with the following commands (do these 1 line at a time.)

```
sudo -s
echo "[default]" >> /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "signing_required=no" >> /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "streams=yes" >> /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "file_ids_off=yes" >> /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "protocol_vers_map=2" >> /etc/nsmb.conf
```

When checking the ownership of the file using "ls -l" the user should be root and the group should be wheel, if it isn't use the following command:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/nsmb.conf
```

The permissions of the file should also be as follows:

```
User  - Read + Write
Group - Read
Other - Read
```

if not use the following command:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/nsmb.conf
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try and let you know if it worked. Thank you.Best Regads

Comment: i have tested this command  but i get an error message i have no access on the server please contact your administrator  **[default]
signing_required=no
streams=yes
file_ids_off=yes
protocol_vers_map=2**

Comment: That is not a command, you need to put that in a file called `nsmb.conf` in the location `/etc/`.

Comment: I will say it would be best to restart the mac after as well so that all smb connections are fresh connections and therefore the new configuration is used.

Comment: I have also edited the answer with instructions / commands to create the file and insert the required lines.

Comment: okey i will try and come back for feedback Thank you Best Regards

Comment: i have try this metod but is the same

Comment: Just to confirm you are using the commands in the terminal?

Comment: Yes i use commands in the terminal

Comment: What error are you receiving now, also do you have access to an admins account? `sudo` requires an account with admin access as it functions as root.

Comment: Also at what point are you experiencing the issue?, is it when you are connecting to the server itself?, if this is the case you may need to change `signing_required=no` to `signing_required=yes` by editing `/etc/nsmb.conf` with `nano` or `vi`, its possible that signing is enforced by the server. Can you please also confirm if SMB V2 is enabled on the server or are you reliant on SMB V3?

Comment: i have used the command and customized nsmb.conf but when i try to connect to the network drive it fails. you cant connect to server.. any idea why...Best Regards